# Julia: Arrays with abstract parameters cause errors but variables with abstract types don't

Tags: julia

The [Julia style guide](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#don-t-use-unnecessary-static-parameters) says the following:

> Don’t use unnecessary static parameters. A function signature:
>
> ```
> foo{T<:Real}(x::T) = ...
> ```
>
> should be written as:
>
> ```
> foo(x::Real) = ...
> ```

I expected that to apply to array parameters too. However, if I write the following code:

```
ret1(x::Real) = x
ret2(x::Array{Float64,2}) = x
ret3(x::Array{Real,2}) = x
ret1(1.0)
ret2(rand(2,2))
ret3(rand(2,2))
```

then I get the following console output (using Julia 0.2.1):

```
MethodError(ret3,(
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.841121  0.322133
 0.469432  0.495438,))
```

So why does Julia throw an error for arrays with abstract type parameters, but not for variables with abstract types?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of `ret3`, the type parameter is actually necessary because <s>an `Array{Real}` is a type that can never be constructed</s> Julia's type parameters are invariant. This is a bit of a subtle topic but the key fact is that while `Float64 <: Real` is true, `Array{Float64} <: Array{Real}` is *not*. This is a bit confusing at first, but this is necessary for the compiler to be able to know the memory layout of function arguments when doing code generation. See the [manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/) for more on this.

So you can dispatch on a `Real` as in `ret1` because when you pass it a `Float64`, `Float64 <: Real` is true, whereas in `ret3` you are passing it a `Array{Float64}`, and `Array{Float64} <: Array{Real}` is not the case, hence the no method error. To fix this, use a type parameter:

```
julia> ret3{T <: Real}(x::Array{T,2}) = x
ret3 (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> ret3(rand(2,2))
2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0857132  0.353194
 0.802737   0.717292
```

Comment: Yes, I thought that would be the answer. But then it requires static parameters which would otherwise seem unnecessary. Why doesn't Julia have an array type which enforces all elements being the same type?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, Julia an infinite number of array types that enforce all elements being the same type: `Array{Float64}`, `Array{String}`, etc., etc. Does you mean something that enforces elements being of the same type without having to specify what the type is?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is an array type such as ArrayHomogenous{T} where T can be an abstract type such as Real or Number, but for which the compiler knows that every element will be the same type, whatever that type may be.

Comment: That's a good question, but my guess is because it isn't really that useful in practice — you almost always pass homogenous arrays of a concrete type as arguments anyway and the compiler is able to specialize on that. Having an array whose elements are all guaranteed to be some subtype of `Real` is not particularly useful without specifying *which subtype* since without that information almost no structural information is being provided to the compiler (e.g. about memory layout, etc.).

Comment: I'd make one very small change to James' answer: `Array{Real}` can be constructed, which is why `x::Array{Real}` is taken to refer to a unique concrete type, but `Real` cannot be constructed, so `x::Real` can be safely taken to refer to a family of many concrete types.

Comment: John is right of course, I answered in haste. `a = Real[1,1.0]` is perfectly valid and does what you would expect. edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of `ret3`, a strictly `Array{Real, 2}` is expected, i.e., an array which can hold any kind of `Real` variables inside (while `rand(2,2)` is an array of `Float64` only).

In this case the static parameter is not unnecessary:

```
ret3{T<:Real}(x::Array{T,2}) = x
```

Answer (score 0):

As of julia 1.2, I believe the appropriate typing for `ret3` is:

```
ret3(x::Array{<:Real,2})
```